# jquery MatchHeight plugin not working as expected

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using the [MatchHeight.js](https://github.com/liabru/jquery-match-height) plugin on a Bootstrap 3.3.6 website.

Although I've managed to use this successfully on other parts of my website I cannot get it to work on the page on which I'm currently working. All source files are loaded correctly so I know it's not a missing library or other such issue.

The markup I'm working with is intended to output a grid showing 3 news articles. The images inside each one may be different proportions. So the issue is that if the images are not all the same height (and they are not, in this case) I wanted to use MatchHeight.js to make the boxes keep to the same height.

The markup I have is like this:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail text-center match-height">
                <img alt="" class="img-responsive" src=
                "image1.jpg">

                <div class="caption">
                   <h4>Quick summary of a question that's been asked</h4>
                   <p class="date">19 January 2017</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail text-center match-height">
                <img alt="" class="img-responsive" src=
                "image2.jpg">

                <div class="caption">
                    <h4>Quick summary of a question that's been asked</h4>
                    <p class="date">19 January 2017</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail text-center match-height">
                <img alt="" class="img-responsive" src=
                "image3.jpg">

                <div class="caption">
                    <h4>Quick summary of a question that's been asked</h4>
                    <p class="date">19 January 2017</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The class `.match-height` has been added to those div's so that the plugin will be applied like this:

```
$('.match-height').matchHeight();
```

But it doesn't seem to work.
On other parts of my site I've used this approach succesfully, although no images were involved, the boxes just contained text.

The goal is just to have equal height boxes regardless of the image proportions used. Is this even possible?

#### Edit

A solution I've come up with was to add the `.match-height` class to the **img** tag. Doesn't seem appropriate, but this does actually work. If anyone has a better solution let me know.

Comment: I've done this without plugins by creating a array of elements. Checking which one has the biggest height and then setting the rest to the same height.

Comment: Are you able to post an example?

Comment: I've posted my example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go.

Example of getting the highest height of select divs and setting all to the same height.

If you want to do this with images, it wont work that well because the proportions would go out.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var array = $(".match-height");
        var height = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            if($(array[i]).height() > height){
                height = $(array[i]).height();
            }
        }
        $(array).height(height);
    });
```